# How to run ffmpeg on a AMD GPU

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, amd-gpu

How to run ffmpeg under Ubuntu on an AMD GPU.

https://jcutrer.com/howto/ffmpeg-amd-nvidia-hardware-video-encoding-h264-h265

I am using the codes on this site. But the GPU commands do not work. I'm not sure if my GPU driver is installed.

I write `ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v h264_amf output.mp4` when, `Unknown encoder 'h264_amf`

Comment: "do not work" -- how do they not work? Please show the codes you use and the error messages or output problems you receive in return. If you suspect a driver issue, please give details about your graphics card and the driver you installed (with the command you used to install it).

Comment: I write ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v h264_amf output.mp4 when ,Unknown encoder 'h264_amf'

Comment: That's very important info: you should [edit] your question to include that info.

Answer (score 2):

To use h264_amf, you have to build ffmpeg with support for that encoder using the

```
--build-amd-amf=y
```

flag. See the [Windows build helpers project](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers) for more info.

On linux, use

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_vaapi
```

instead. And see [How to use GPU acceleration in FFmpeg with AMD Radeon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107782/how-to-use-gpu-acceleration-in-ffmpeg-with-amd-radeon)
 on askubuntu.

Comment: in ubuntu please.

Comment: Please include specs in the original question. I've editing my answer to include ubuntu.

Comment: thank you for your help but i couldn't find a soltion. ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 output.mp4 ,it's run but i can't do it with gpu.